# Extracting Data from array of hashes Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Given that I have the following array of hashes

```
@response =  { "0"=>{"forename_1"=>"John", "surname_1"=>"Smith"}, 
               "1"=>{"forename_1"=>"Chris", "surname_1"=>"Jenkins"}, 
               "2"=>{"forename_1"=>"Billy", "surname_1"=>"Bob"},
               "Status" => 100
             }
```

I am looking to create an array of the `forename_1` and `surname_1` values combined, so desired output would be

```
["John Smith", "Chris Jenkins", "Billy Bob"]
```

So I can get this far, but need further assistance

```
# Delete the Status as not needed
@response.delete_if { |k| ["Status"].include? k }

@response.each do |key, value|
  puts key
  #This will print out 0 1 2
  puts value
  # This will print {"forename_1"=>"John", "surname_1"=>"Smith"}, "{"forename_1"=>"Chris", "surname_1"=>"Jenkins"}, "{"forename_1"=>"Billy", "surname_1"=>"Bob"}
  puts value.keys
 # prints ["forename_1", "surname_1"], ["forename_1", "surname_1"], ["forename_1", "surname_1"] 
  puts value.values
  # prints ["John", "Smith"], ["Chris", "Jenkins"], ["Billy", "Bob"] 
  value.map { |v| v["forename_1"] }
  # However i get no implicit conversion of String into Integer error
end
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is to get the values of the `@response` hash, filter out what is not an instance of `Hash`, and then join together the forename and the surname, I would do something like this:

```
@response.values.grep(Hash).map { |h| "#{h['forename_1']} #{h['surname_1']}" }
# => ["John Smith", "Chris Jenkins", "Billy Bob"]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a neat way of putting it together

Answer (score 2):

Another way :

```
@response.values.grep(Hash).map { |t| t.values.join(' ')}
```

Comment: Only works if he KNOWS that the values of that hash always comes in that order. The order is fixed in ruby but the data might come from other sources.

Answer (score 1):

```
@response.values.map{ |res| 
   [res["forename_1"] , res["surname_1"]].join(' ')  if res.is_a?(Hash)  
}.compact
```